# Getting destination member expression by source expression in AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

Let say I have mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CalendarEvent, CalendarEventForm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EventDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventDate.Date))
```

Is it possible to get back the destination member expression by its relative source expression. Something like this:

```
Expression<Func<CalendarEventForm, object>> destinationExpression = Mapper.GetMemmberExpression(src => src.EventDate.Date);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess would be "no" since the anonymous methods generated by lambda expressions don't have any concept of comparing each other for equality.  Why do you need something like this?

Comment: I want to be able on client side to sort and group by specifying DTO properties (as lambda expressions) and sending them to the server (where actually sorting and grouping are done). So my idea is to map DTO property selector to Entity property selector. I realize there is no such possibility in the current version of AutoMapper, but looking at Mapper.CreateMapExpression() make me feel its no so hard to be implemented. Am I wrong?